# I am using mixins in Less for 1st time. How to use '!important' declarations & multiple values in single property

Tags: html, css, less

I created a function inside Variable.LESS

```
.b-radius(@r)
{ border-radius: @r;
  -moz-border-radius: @r;
  -webkit-border-radius: @r;
}
```

Then i used the above code into my Style.LESS file as

```
.alert {
    .b-radius(2px);
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But how can i use @b-radius where i am having

```
Case 1 - 
.alert2 {
    border-radius:10px !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

Case 2 - 
.alert3 {
    border-radius:0 10px 3px 9px !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Just do `.b-radius(2px) !important`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: .b-radius(2px) !important this is working. Please tell me another case2 also It will be a favour.

Comment: You can do `.b-radius(0 10px 3px 9px) !important`.